# How to use jQuery to find a link within the div with a certain class and make it inactive

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

How to use jQuery to find a link within the div with a certain class and make it inactive, that is to deprive the property links to her it was impossible to push.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$("div.someClass").find("a").removeAttr("href");
```

or if you would rather not get rid of the href attribute:

```
$("div.someClass a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I suggest the second option. More verbose, but less "hacky", and the document remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$("div.classToFind a").click(function() { return false; });
```